# What optimizations are enabled by strict aliasing?

Tags: c++, c++20, reinterpret-cast

Consider this example:

```cpp
// standard-layout
struct S {
    float x;
    int y;
};

// not inlineable
void f(float* p); /* {
    reinterpret_cast<S*>(p)->y = 43;
} */

int test_f() {
    S s{0.0f, 42};
    // value of p is "pointer to s.x", s.x and s are pointer-interconvertible,
    // so f() could access s.y through p
    float *p = &s.x;
    f(p);
    return s.y; // not 42?
}

void g(int* p);

float test_g() {
    S s{0.0f, 42};
    // value of p is "pointer to s.y", s.y and s are not pointer-interconvertible,
    // so g() can't access s.x through p
    int *p = &s.y;
    g(p);
    return s.x; // always 0.0f
}
```

Am I correct to assume that `f()` is allowed access to `s.y` through `&s.x`? While `test_g()` always returns `0.0f`, because `g()` may not access `s.x` through `&s.y`.

What if `y` were `std::byte`, would the more permissive aliasing preclude this optimization in `test_g()`?

Comment: `std::launder` is not required here. It needs to be used if the objects are _not_ pointer-interconvertible.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I'll remove the reference to `std::launder`.

Comment: In the title the reference was appropriate. The restriction you are talking about is the `std::launder` precondition, but just your particular example happens to not require it in the `f` case. Strict aliasing is not relevant.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the sort of optimizations a compiler can make based on strict aliasing rules (i.e. the limitations designed into `reinterpret_cast` and `std::launder()`), with focus on particular example. Is the question not clear?

Comment: The question is clear, but strict aliasing is only about which pointer types may be used to access an object. Reachability is about which objects/bytes can be reached via a pointer to another object. So strict aliasing isn't really relevant to your question and the original title was better. `std::launder` was just not needed in `f`, because `reinterpret_cast` already gives a pointer to the object of the requested type if the objects are pointer-interconvertible. `std::launder` can be used if they are not pointer-interconvertible but the reachability precondition is satisfied.

Comment: I'm (ab)using strict aliasing in a broader form which implies reachability, just to keep the title short. Anyone who'd prefer something more precise has my blessing to edit.